# How to change the color of the selected row in a data table ace

Tags: jsf, icefaces

My question is how you can change the color of the selected row in a datatable ace, as the default color is dark blue.

Comment: Needs more information. When do you need a selected row to change colour ? If it's dynamic you could use jQuery for this.

Comment: Yes. it's dynamic... I use this to navigate through the records or perform some action to select a particular row.

Comment: Ok. Haven't used icefaces but to change appearance what you can do is something like this in jQuery: `$("td").click(function(){$(this).attr("background-color","green");});`. A loop can be added to reset the `background-color` on all the other TDs. Some ajax can also be used to interact with Servlets. Let me know if this answer suits you and I will be happy to detail the code.

Comment: Just throw in some CSS.

Comment: How could this be done: excuse my ignorance but of icefaces datatable are somewhat limited to such requests and made ​​hey not know how. Would greatly appreciate your help